# Can Serilog return the value of resulting action rather than the data type?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have Serilog in a .net core 2.1 web API using the Serilog.AspNetCore package. When an action gets called the incoming parameters are logged:

```
[INF] Executing action method WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApi) with arguments (["4"]) - Validation state: "Valid"
```

But when the action is done I get the following less useful lines:

```
[INF] Executed action method WebApi.Controllers.ValuesController.Get (WebApi), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult in 8.2537ms.
[INF] Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'.
```

I'd prefer the actual values.  For example, the Dictionary should just be json.

Is there a way to override this default behavior?

Comment: Have you seen [Formatting Ouput](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Formatting-Output#format-providers) in the docs?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that but I'm not sure it applies.  The logging I'm talking about actually has no code.  If I was calling 'logger.Information()' in the code I could apply the Formatting.Output, but the lines above happen automagically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Serilog**, it could return json data type, but, you could not change the built-in return value for `Executing ObjectResult`. This is controlled by [ObjectResultExecuting](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/667ad4daff242d4a09f4ca68836e8aa3e10b5a02/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/MvcCoreLoggerExtensions.cs#L881), and this is hard-code.

```cs
public static void ObjectResultExecuting(this ILogger logger, object value)
{
    if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information))
    {
        var type = value == null ? "null" : value.GetType().FullName;
        _objectResultExecuting(logger, type, null);
    }
}
```

`ObjectResultExecuting` logs the type instead of the value. I assume it is for better performance. You could assume that if you serialize the response to string, it will waste a lot performance, and there is no need for that.

If you prefer to log the specific response, you may try to log in the method by yourself.

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SerilogController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<SerilogController> _log;
    public SerilogController(ILogger<SerilogController> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(string password)
    {
        _log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new string[] { "value1", "value2" }));
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```